# Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined on a specific page

Tags: next.js, knex.js

We use next.js with knex.js as query builder, in all pages everything is OK except in one page that we have ISR aka `getStaticPaths` and in that method we get the following error whenever we try to execute a query, but in other pages that do not have `getStaticPaths` everything works fine:

```
Server Error
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete]
node:dns (71:26)
```

no more info is provided anywhere else. as it is shown in the error message, the database host is undefined but why it read correctly everywhere except in `getStaticPaths`??

Answer (score 0):

Turns out we had this experimental feature tuned on in `next.config.js`, when it is turned on .env variables are all undefined and not loaded correctly inside `getStaticPaths` but once the `getStaticProps` is called everything is OK, I do not know the reason for this, but turning `workerThreads` off solved the problem:

```
experimental: {
    workerThreads: false //fixed the problem
},
```